# convert <class 'dict'> to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

How to convert please this <class 'dict'> to pandas DataFrame

```
{0: array([[32660, 28584, 29515, ..., 33589, 30393, 32111],
       [32401, 29686, 30142, ..., 33693, 31156, 31867],
       [32152, 30873, 30402, ..., 33564, 31729, 31504],
       ...,
       [35969, 36967, 35417, ..., 34458, 35129, 33801],
       [36215, 37024, 34740, ..., 34762, 34381, 33896],
       [35686, 36373, 33853, ..., 34721, 33456, 33680]])}
```

I tried a lot of syntaxe but it doesn't work.

Any Help please

Comment: In what format your output dataframe should be? how many column it should have? Post a sample dataframe.

Comment: I have a big dict DataFrame, it consist of 255 lines and more than 1500 columns.
So to use this data i should first convert it to pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the below code to your number of columns and give it appropriate column names.

```
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

dct = {0: array([[32660, 28584, 29515, 33589, 30393, 32111],
       [32401, 29686, 30142,  33693, 31156, 31867],
       [32152, 30873, 30402,  33564, 31729, 31504],
       [35969, 36967, 35417, 34458, 35129, 33801],
       [36215, 37024, 34740, 34762, 34381, 33896],
       [35686, 36373, 33853, 34721, 33456, 33680]])}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct[0], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32660 | 28584 | 29515 | 33589 | 30393 | 32111 |
| 1 | 32401 | 29686 | 30142 | 33693 | 31156 | 31867 |
| 2 | 32152 | 30873 | 30402 | 33564 | 31729 | 31504 |
| 3 | 35969 | 36967 | 35417 | 34458 | 35129 | 33801 |
| 4 | 36215 | 37024 | 34740 | 34762 | 34381 | 33896 |
| 5 | 35686 | 36373 | 33853 | 34721 | 33456 | 33680 |

**Edit: without column names**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dct[0])
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32660 | 28584 | 29515 | 33589 | 30393 | 32111 |
| 1 | 32401 | 29686 | 30142 | 33693 | 31156 | 31867 |
| 2 | 32152 | 30873 | 30402 | 33564 | 31729 | 31504 |
| 3 | 35969 | 36967 | 35417 | 34458 | 35129 | 33801 |
| 4 | 36215 | 37024 | 34740 | 34762 | 34381 | 33896 |
| 5 | 35686 | 36373 | 33853 | 34721 | 33456 | 33680 |

Comment: I'm agree with you in this case, but in my case i have 255 lines and more than 1500 columns.

Comment: Just leave out the `columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` part if your data doesn't have column names.